# sending sms from servlet to phone

Tags: servlets, sms

I have my servlet that has a method that randomly generates passwords. I want it to be able to send each generated password to a specified phone number. What do I need to do? I read somewhere that it is possible using a GSM modem which I have. Any one tell me how to interface the servlet and the modem to send the sms

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=22); this shows how to send SMS from modem using AT commands. You can use it in your servlet.

Comment: Thank you @Harry. Let me give it a try